# Proguard with In-app purchase "Duplicate zip entry" error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, proguard, in-app-billing

I am using In app billing (followed steps as per developer.android.com) that includes a file 
InAppBillingService.aidl

As suggested here -> http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html
We need to obfuscate the code using Progaurd for security reasons.

Now exporting a signed apk with proguard enabled gives me the following error.

Duplicate zip entry [android_6861407322325970495.jar:com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]

Any ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Following is the complete trace.

```
java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Temp\android_2083818169284424504.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Temp\android_6558830429113811056.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [android_6558830429113811056.jar:com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]))
at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:264)
at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:160)
at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:372)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:153)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Temp\android_6558830429113811056.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [android_6558830429113811056.jar:com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class])
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)
at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:253)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [android_6558830429113811056.jar:com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]
at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:139)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
... 6 more
```

Comment: how did u solve it? -injars is not workin in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps you,

according to ProGuard docs:

> Warning: can't write resource ... Duplicate zip entry
>       Your input jars contain multiple resource files with the same name. ProGuard continues copying the resource files as usual, skipping
>   any files with previously used names. Once more, the warning may be an
>   indication of some problem though, so it's advisable to remove the
>   duplicates. A convenient way to do so is by specifying filters on the
>   input jars. There is no option to switch off these warnings.

You have a duplicate resource entry "IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class" in your library jar android_6558830429113811056.jar

You can try using `-outjars`

> -outjars class_path
>       Specifies the names of the output jars (or wars, ears, zips, or directories). The processed input of the preceding -injars options
>   will be written to the named jars. This allows you to collect the
>   contents of groups of input jars into corresponding groups of output
>   jars. In addition, the output entries can be filtered, as explained in
>   the filters section. Each processed class file or resource file is
>   then written to the first output entry with a matching filter, within
>   the group of output jars.
>
> You must avoid letting the output files overwrite any input files. For better
>   readability, class path entries can be specified using multiple -outjars options.
>   Without any -outjars options, no jars will be written.

or if you are using `-injars` you can configure a [filter](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#filtering)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there indeed is a duplicate entry. Probably some library is available both as a dependency and as a copy in a subdirectory. The error probably shows even without proguard.

There should be intermediate apk-s, you may try to see what's inside the newest apk.

I'd also suggest trying to build from a command line. (OTOH, the last time I tried that I faced very non-informative errors, something of the sort "null returned 1", that is, non-zero error code from nobody knows what component, there was something more informative in the logs.)

You may also try to manually delete the error messages (select them (the leafs only, not their root) in the window and press "Del"), clean the project and build it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Clean/re-build does nothing. Also its not a compile time error and without progaurd everything is good. Can't delete the error. The error appears when the real obfuscation is being applied when signing with a keystore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have `-injars bin/classes` in your ProGuard config, try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running proguard with the `-verbose` option?  You may be able to see exactly what (and when) the duplicate library is being added.